# org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor@6ea2bc93 is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, clickhouse

**flink consume kafka, sink to clickhouse**

error at `dataStreamSource.addSink(sinkInstance);`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor@6ea2bc93 is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2000)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1243)
    at org.data.dataflow.KafkaToFlink.main(KafkaToFlink.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:143)
    ... 11 more
```

```java
public class KafkaToFlink {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment
        .getExecutionEnvironment().setParallelism(1);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "10.227.89.202:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> dataStreamSource = streamExecutionEnvironment
        .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
            "my-topic",
            new CustomKafkaDeserializationSchema(),
            properties).setStartFromEarliest()
        ).map((MapFunction<String, String>) s -> {
          Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 500));
          return s;
        });
    SinkFunction<String> sinkInstance = new FlinkToCK("xxx", 8123 + "", "default", "");
    dataStreamSource.addSink(sinkInstance);
    streamExecutionEnvironment.execute("flink consume kafka topic");
  }
}

class CustomKafkaDeserializationSchema implements KafkaDeserializationSchema<String> {

  @Override
  public boolean isEndOfStream(String s) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
    return consumerRecord.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public TypeInformation<String> getProducedType() {
    return BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO;
  }
}
```

```java
class FlinkToCK extends RichSinkFunction<String> {

  FlinkToCK(String host, String port, String user, String pwd) throws SQLException {
    super();
    this.connection_ = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:clickhouse://" + host + ":" + port, user, pwd);
    this.statement_ = connection_.createStatement();
    statement_.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test");
  }

  @Override
  public void invoke(String value, SinkFunction.Context context) throws SQLException {
    statement_.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('${value}')");
  }

  public void close() throws SQLException {
    connection_.close();
  }

  private final Connection connection_;
  private final Statement statement_;
}
```

Comment: Your deserializer should be for the Kafka key or the value, not the consumer record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the fact that `Connection` is not serializable because it contains reference to `HttpRequestExecutor`, what You may try to do, is to make Connection and statement `transient`. Then, instead of assigning them inside the constructor You should override the `open()` method and there You can open the DB connection and create a new `Statement`, but that means they can't be `final` in this case.